# Ubuntu Transparent Gnome Terminal

Tags: ubuntu

I want to know that how to make Transparent Gnome Terminal in Ubuntu for all application, i know that we can do transparent terminal for desktop not for all application. I have googled a lot but unable to find out any solutions of it . Can anyone tell me that how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Here you can check it.. 
askubuntu.com/questions/74114/how-to-make-terminal-semi-transparent

Answer (score 1):

here you go.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/133286/how-can-i-make-my-windows-transparent-by-doing-altmouse-scroll

There is a tool called `Compiz` which is a window manager. it can provide the effects you are looking for.. the linked article details how to install and use/configure it.

Comment: Hi Anantha thanks for ur suggestion but i also found out solution and its very cool, no need to install any tool i think we just have to enabled it, Its a command that worked for me(gconftool-2 -s '/apps/metacity/general/compositing_manager' --type bool true) I am going to share a link :-
it makes it transparent for all application its cool, i am going to share a link as well.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/74114/how-to-make-terminal-semi-transparent

Comment: askubuntu.com/questions/74114/how-to-make-terminal-semi-transparent

Answer (score 0):

It works off the bat in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

[image: Terminal settings]

Use the "Use transparent background" slider and set the profile as active.